# How to make sum of double value in a string in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have a simple string formatted like that `(2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0)`

I don't found how to simply make a sum of each value `2.0+1.0+1.0+3.0+5.0 = 11.0`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do is like this.

```
  String str = "(2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0)";
  str = str.replaceAll("(","");
  str = str.replaceAll(")","");
  List<String> strDoubles = str.split(", ");
  
  double sum = 0;
  strDoubles.forEach((String item){
    sum = sum + double.parse(item);
  });
  print(sum);       //<-- prints 12
```

Comment: Thank you ! I would never have found